# PTIJ: Is there a Y'dei Esav Siddur?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There has been a siddur around for many years called קול יעקב. I assume that the name of the Siddur was inspired by [Breishit 27:22](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=346):

> הקול קול יעקב והידים ידי עשיו

I also understand that the Siddur is used for prayer or, in a sense, speaking to G-d, so this seems like a good name for a Siddur.

However, we really pray with our entire bodies, including our hands. Our hands have to hold the Siddur, carry the Torah, wear tefillin, and do other things involved with prayer. I haven't seen a Siddur called *Y'dei Esav*. It seems like this would be a decent name, as long as we have alluded to this verse, already to name a siddur. Is there such a Siddur around, and if so, where can I buy one? If not, why isn't there one?

For those who insist that Esav was an evil man, I counter that there is nothing stated directly in the Torah that says this. Additionally, even a number of rabbis have commended his loyalty and commitment to honoring his father. To me, that feature alone should let him have a Siddur named after him. Wouldn't we want to pray for children honoring their parents? There are, sadly, many kids that don't do this.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: The siddur קול יעקב is nusach Ashkenaz. That leaves Y'dei Esav available for other nuschaos. (not intended to be taken seriously.)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Not the Kol Yaakov I'm most familiar with, which is Nusach Sefard.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is.  It is mentioned in Sefer Lechem Hapanim [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8plEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT46&lpg=PT46&dq=%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%95&source=bl&ots=inlGIkbd5q&sig=2mfo8hewBol9WFKOKx0RWM1It2c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinhdqv9LTZAhVMyoMKHdWGDCAQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q=%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%95&f=false). (Ironically, it fills in the first letter of the name Yaakov.)

It is also mentioned by Rabbeinu Bachya/Bechaya ([Bereishis 32:12](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._Bachya/Bereshit/32.12#t2e0n7)), that the Siddur Yedei Esav was Davened from for many generations, including by David Hamelech:

> ויתכן לפרש כי התפלל לשעה ולדורות, מיד אחי לשעה, מיד עשו לדורות. והוא שכתוב (בראשית כז) והידים ידי עשו, ועליו התפלל דוד ע״ה

Comment: Go figure. Can you summarize what that page is saying? I get the Hebrew, but I'm really missing the concept of what he says in relation to what the rest if the sefer is about.

Comment: @DanF again, in Purim Torah I don't feel that there is a point in writing what it really says with my serious hat on.  My point is that it says "Yedei Esav Siddur", and the Y in Yedei actually stands for the Y in Yaakov.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the smart phone used as a Siddur is a Yedai Eisav Siddur. [This is per Shalom Mordechai Rubashkin](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/1453727/watch-this-rubashkin-blasts-people-who-use-smartphone-to-daven-in-shul.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no Siddur Y'dei Eisav. What the passuk is trying to convey is that when Eisav did teshuvah, he bought a Siddur Kol Yaakov. While davening with it, Yitzchak heard him. Now that Eisav was saying holy words, Yitzchak said:

> "The voice is Yaakov's, but the hands are Eisav's!"

Yitzchak became so confused he died.

Comment: Apologies, but I also became so confused...  I don't get it.